# Adding a menu with radio boxes or check boxes

Tags: menu-bar

How do you create options with radio boxes or check boxes in the menu bar?  I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See standard library `menu-bar.el` and `C-h f menu-bar-make-toggle`. Here are some examples from standard Emacs libraries.

For a checkbox (from `menu-bar.el`:

```el
(define-key menu-bar-options-menu [case-fold-search]
  (menu-bar-make-toggle
    toggle-case-fold-search case-fold-search
    "Ignore Case for Search"
    "Case-Insensitive Search %s"
    "Ignore letter-case in search commands"))
```

For a radio button (from `bubbles.el`):

```el
(define-key bubbles-game-theme-menu [bubbles-set-game-hard]
  (list 'menu-item "Hard" 'bubbles-set-game-hard
        :button '(:radio . (eq bubbles-game-theme 'hard))))
```

See also the Elisp manual, node [Extended Menu Items](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extended-Menu-Items.html).

Comment: Thanks, Drew.  Radio buttons are so complicated!  I will find another way to select options.

Comment: I updated the answer with a simpler `:radio` example.  Just `grep` the Lisp source code for `:radio` to find more.